# Deploy firebase function - No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I was trying to deploy the firebase-cloud function:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const app = require("express")();
const { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } = require("firebase/auth");
const auth = getAuth();
const firebase = require("firebase/app");

admin.initializeApp();

const config = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: " ",
  projectId: " ",
  storageBucket: " ",
  messagingSenderId: " ",
  appId: " ",
  measurementId: " ",
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
//Signup Route
app.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
  const newUser = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
  };
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, newUser.email, newUser.password)
    .then((data) => {
      return res
        .status(201)
        .json({ message: `user ${data.user.uuid} signed up successfully` });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
    });
});

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

But I gotthis error

> FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).

[image: Image Here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be trying to import the client-side JavaScript/Web SDK here:

```
const { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } = require("firebase/auth");
const auth = getAuth();
const firebase = require("firebase/app");
```

That SDK is not support in Cloud Functions. Instead you should use the Admin SDK for Node.ks, which you're already importing too with:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
```

To [create a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) with the Admin SDK:

```
admin
  .auth()
  .createUser({
    email: 'user@example.com',
    emailVerified: false,
    phoneNumber: '+11234567890',
    password: 'secretPassword',
    displayName: 'John Doe',
    photoURL: 'http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png',
    disabled: false,
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with Cloud Functions in a Firebase project, I received the same error. Since Cloud Functions is a trusted environment, you don't need to provide   `config` argument to the `initializeApp()`.
Steps to reproduce the error:

```
import { initializeApp} from 'firebase-admin/app';
var config = {
  apiKey: .....,
  authDomain = ...,
  ...
}
const app = initializeApp(config);
```

This worked for me:

```
import { initializeApp} from 'firebase-admin/app';
const app = initializeApp();
```

I am using `Firebase v9`, and `firebase-admin SDK v10`.