# Following Firebase tutorial, and getting Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

So I'm new to creating login pages and my backend is in Django.

But I thought I could follow the simple instructions here:
https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web

I copied the example code they provide then went to the Firebase console to get my appl initialization settings and pasted it into the section where the code said I should but I get this error:

> Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase     App.initializeApp() (app-compat/no-app)

and when rendering the page through Django instead of showing a login box it displays my config parameters as text.

My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sample FirebaseUI App</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>
    
    <script type="module">
        // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
        import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.1/firebase-app.js";
        import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.1/firebase-analytics.js";
        // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
      
        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
        const firebaseConfig = {
          apiKey: "XXX",
          authDomain: "XXX",
          projectId: "XXX",
          storageBucket: "XXX",
          messagingSenderId: "XXX",
          appId: "XXX",
          measurementId: "XXX"
        };
      
        // Initialize Firebase
        const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
    </script>
    
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/6.0.2/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/6.0.2/firebase-ui-auth.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // FirebaseUI config.
      var uiConfig = {
        signInSuccessUrl: 'www.bbco.co.uk',
        signInOptions: [
          // Leave the lines as is for the providers you want to offer your users.
          firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          firebaseui.auth.AnonymousAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
        ],
        // tosUrl and privacyPolicyUrl accept either url string or a callback
        // function.
        // Terms of service url/callback.
        tosUrl: '<your-tos-url>',
        // Privacy policy url/callback.
        privacyPolicyUrl: function() {
          window.location.assign('<your-privacy-policy-url>');
        }
      };

      // Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
      
      var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
      // The start method will wait until the DOM is loaded.
      ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- The surrounding HTML is left untouched by FirebaseUI.
         Your app may use that space for branding, controls and other customizations.-->
    <h1>Welcome to My Awesome App</h1>
    <div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I did try asking ChatGPT and it did say:

> "indicates that the Firebase app is not being initialized properly, or
> It's being called before the initialization.
>
> The issue here is due to the mix of Firebase v9 (modular) and v8
> (compact) in your code. The Firebase UI library you're using
> (firebase-ui-auth.js) is not yet compatible with v9 at the time of the
> last training cut-off in September 2021."

What I don't get is that I'm simply following the instructions that Firebase provided.

I've also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69577258/deploy-firebase-function-no-firebase-app-default-has-been-created) but I'm not using cloud functions so not sure if the solution applies.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I managed to get it to work through a combination of my own searches and back and forth with ChatGPT.

Exaplanation is:
I was mixing of Firebase version 9 module-based syntax with the older namespace (version 8 and below) syntax.

In Firebase version 9, the SDK has been updated to use ES Modules. Because of this, the firebase namespace is not used anymore, and you must import each feature individually. But I was trying to use the new module-based SDK with the old firebase namespace, which is causing the error.

Correct solution is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sample FirebaseUI App</title>
    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>

    <!-- FirebaseUI for Authentication -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/6.0.2/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/6.0.2/firebase-ui-auth.css" />

    <script>
        var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "XXXX",
            authDomain: "XXX",
            projectId: "XXX",
            storageBucket: "XXX",
            messagingSenderId: "XXX",
            appId: "XXX",
            measurementId: "XXX"
            };

        // Initialize Firebase
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    </script>

    <script>
        // FirebaseUI config.
        var uiConfig = {
            signInSuccessUrl: '/success.html',
            signInOptions: [
                // Leave the lines as is for the providers you want to offer your users.
                firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                firebaseui.auth.AnonymousAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
            ],
            tosUrl: '<your-tos-url>',
            privacyPolicyUrl: function() {
                window.location.assign('<your-privacy-policy-url>');
            }
        };

        // Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
        var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
        // The start method will wait until the DOM is loaded.
        ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to My Awesome App</h1>
    <div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```